# Spring Boot webflux - offload requests to a different threadpool

Tags: spring, spring-boot, blocking, webflux

I'm using webflux with netty reactor.
The framework allows registering a regular blocking method (e.g that returns a string or some POJO) in a @RestController class.
The issue with that is the requests are running on netty's event loop, which you don't want to block.
My question is - is there a way to **generically** offload such methods (by looking at the return type, for example) to a different, dedicated, thread pool?

I've tried doing it in a WebFilter that checks the target method and then uses `publishOn` to switch to a different scheduler - this made the filter chain to run on that scheduler, but the method itself was invoked on the eventloop again.
I followed the code path and saw that the `Mono.zip` in `InvocableHandlerMethod::getMethodArgumentValues` is the point where the eventloop is taking over.

Is there a built-in solution to control which threadpool is running the methods invocation?